# R list.files for multiple specific file names

Tags: r, search, directory, find

I have a directory in windows with multiple sub-directories.  I also have a list of file names that I would like to search for within the directory structure (to retrieve exact path)

This works fine for a single value as below (current.folder is a variable for the main directory) -

```
files <- list.files(current.folder, 
                    pattern = test,
                    recursive = TRUE, 
                    full.names = TRUE)
```

I can then use the returned path to do file.copy.

The problem I am now having is applying that function to multiple file names stored in a dataframe or even a vector.

I've tried referencing them in the pattern argument (which only returns for first value) and used a for loop on a set of just two filenames (returns blank).

Am I using the wrong technique or just not finding the correct setup?

Edit for clarification - test refers to value - "1-5FX3C7P_1-5FX3C8T_JNJLFSPROD-ZZFDA-CDRH-AERS-3500A-01162017131543-1-5FX3C7P.xml"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
sapply(test, function(x)list.files(current.folder, 
                                   pattern=x, 
                                   recursive=TRUE,
                                   full.names=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you Dave.  This absolutely worked for a small set of files.  Unfortunately after leaving it overnight it still hasn't completed the full set which is searching for over 3000 in a massive folder structure.  I've marked your answer and upvoted as it is perfect for smaller jobs.  I'll have to figure out another method unless there is something you can suggest

Comment: What about a parallelized for loop?

Comment: Would that be using the map function? I'll have to look into it...

Comment: Or with parSapply, see [here](https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html)

Comment: Awesome suggestion, I'll check it out today